Bad value for restricted picklist field from email message object using screen flow in salesforce
I changed flow into send email action instead of create record element. I'm getting error like Error Occurred: Only User, Contact, Lead, or Person objects are allowed for targetObjectId: 001Ov00000K1J0H.




ValidatedFromAddress must be either the user's email address or an Org-Wide Email Address. a9852aee-2b77-4840-ad3f-69db7d6880a6 isn't a valid email address, much less one that could be in an email field anywhere in Salesforce. Make sure you're using the right value in the From variable.

I tried also but no luck @sfdcfox
